# Using flexbox to dock scrollable container with tab panel (Office UI Fabric Pivot) style layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, office-ui-fabric

I have a layout problem with the Office UI Fabric components I'm using.  This may or not be specific to components in that framework, but I'll phrase this as a general HTML/CSS issue with flexbox.  In general, I'm trying to design a layout that has two grid (DetailsList) components, each in a page type container (Pivot).  I also need the label headers and search box to be fixed to the top, and a button fixed to the bottom (no matter how short the list is in the grid).  If the contents of the list(s) are long I only want scrollbars to be visible in the grid and not the parent container (otherwise you'd have to scroll down to see the Important Button).

I can get this layout to work without a Pivot, using the ScrollablePane component. Like this:

[image: Good docking and scrolling, no Pivot]

However I can't figure out how to design this so the pivot navigators stay fixed to the top as well.  The best I can do is shown in [this example on StackBlitz](https://office-ui-fabric-projectlistlayout.stackblitz.io) ([the editable link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/office-ui-fabric-projectlistlayout)), or as per this screenshot:

[image: Pivot doesn't dock]

Here's a snipped version of the layout as it is currently, with everything docked and scrolling properly except for the pivots scrolling out of view when you scroll the list:

```css
.app-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;  
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
    .app-defaultFlex {
      flex: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    .app-buttonContainer{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background: white
    }
```

```html
    <div id='FlexTest' className='app-wrapper'>
     <div className='header'>
       {header}
     </div>
     <ScrollablePane scrollbarVisibility={ScrollbarVisibility.auto} className='app-defaultFlex'>
      <Pivot>
       <PivotItem id='PivotItemAllProjects' headerText="All Projects">
        <DetailsList items={projectItems}/>
       </PivotItem>
       <PivotItem headerText="Recent" id='PivotItemRecentProjects'>
        <DetailsList items={projectItems}/>
       </PivotItem>
      </Pivot>;
     </ScrollablePane>
     <div className='footer app-buttonContainer'>
       <DefaultButton className='app-FileButton' primary={true} disabled={false}>File to Project</DefaultButton>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to use flexbox to also dock the Pivot tabs to the top so they remain in view?  I've tried multiple variations (see the pivot2 - pivot5 variations in my StackBlitz example) but I can't figure out if this is a problem that can be solved with flexbox, or a limitation to the way I'm using the ScrollablePane component with an embedded Pivot.

**UPDATE 5/28/2019:**

Even if this is distilled down to having just the Pivot component with one PivotItem containing one DetailsList, I don't see how using something like a [Sticky](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/sticky) component or any kind of flex layout can even work, as per this pseudo-code:

```html
<Pivot>
  <Sticky stickyPosition={StickyPositionType.Header}>
 <PivotItem
   id='PivotItemAllProjects'
   headerText="All Projects"
 >
   <DetailstList>
   ..foo
   </DetailsList>
 </PivotItem>
  </Sticky>
</Pivot>
```

Wrapping each individual PivotItem doesn't work - nothing gets rendered at all. Besides, that would imply we want to stick the pivot label AND it's child. Even wrapping the PivotItem in a header Sticky and the child of the PivotItem in a footer Sticky doesn't work.  Am I chasing the impossible here?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Pivots to be in the Scrollable Pane div? If you put the pivots in the header, then you get what you want, no?

Otherwise, you can wrap the Pivots in a Sticky component.

ETA: Wow, I went to link the Sticky component, but seems like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I know what you mean about putting the pivots in the header, I'll try it out. I'll look into the Sticky as well. I found the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/sticky

Comment: I've tried using a Sticky and am still flummoxed. See my updated question, at the end.

Comment: Actually, I think I didn't understand how Pivots worked. I need to think more about this, but my initial thought is to play with styles so that only DetailsList scrolls.